# How can copy ansible nodes ssh keys to all nodes on Ansible?

Tags: ssh, ansible, ssh-keys, ansible-2.x

I would like to generate the ssh key of all my ansible nodes and copy between thems, so all nodes can access among them.

Example:

```
[nodes]
172.16.8.231 node1
172.16.8.232 node2
172.16.8.233 node3
172.16.8.234 node4
```

I would like to copy node1, node2, node3 and node4 ssh keys to all nodes.

So node1 can access to node2, node3 and node4. And same for the rest of the nodes.

I generate the ssh key using the next module:

```
- name: Generate ssh key 
  user:
    name: "{{ user }}"
    generate_ssh_key: yes
    ssh_key_bits: 2048
    ssh_key_file: .ssh/id_rsa
```

I know how to create the ssh key on one node and copy to others, but what I want is to generate ssh key on all nodes and copy to others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know how to create the ssh key on one node and copy to others

No other knowledge is required:

1. generate all key-pairs on a control machine,
2. copy the private keys to their relevant nodes (setting appropriate permissions),
3. add all public keys to `authorized_keys` on all nodes,
4. delete the private keys from the control machine.

<sup>Unless you consider your control machine compromised, there is no increased security risk. Especially as the end goal decreases security significantly.</sup>

Comment: How can I generate all key-pairs on a control machine?, I need the key pairs of all the machines. And I want to have a playbook that now there are 4 nodes, but if I add another node it could work.

Comment: I think I am not explainning what I need. I have 4 nodes, with 4 keys how can I do a playbook on ansible that add the first node key and copy to all the machines, then add the second and same... But if I have 5 nodes I would like to work too

Comment: Yes. Above is my answer.

Comment: Okey really thanks, but I don't understand the control machine, the machines have different ssh-keys how can I generate this on a control machine :S

Comment: I don't understand really thanks but I would remove the question. What you are saying is to create the same private key to all the nodes?, I don't think it would be secure.

Comment: Great attitude! I will register your username so not to make a mistake and answer anymore.

Comment: Okey I use your answer temporarily but I don't think is very secure but it works for me so really thanks. And don't worry for not answering I understand you :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137567/discussion-between-asier-and-techraf).